# Крашется компилятор qt

Tags: c++, qt

При отладки кода на c++, IDE выводит вот такое сообщение: 
FTH: (11040): *** Fault tolerant heap shim applied to current process. This is usually due to previous crashes. ***
Гугл не помогает..
Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Ничего у вас не крашится. Это уведомление о том, что ваша программа часто падала (и это неудивительно, во время разработки-то), а потому ей будет предоставляться специальный диспетчер памяти, более простительный к выходам за границы массивов. Так как это всего лишь служебное уведомление, смело его игнорируйте — на вас оно никак не влияет.

Comment: Гугл утверждает, что игнорировать его не стоит - `This is a real problem since it masks the bug I am trying to reproduce, and it also kills performance`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Это уведомление о том, что ваша программа часто падала (и это неудивительно, во время разработки-то), а потому ей будет предоставляться специальный диспетчер памяти, более простительный к выходам за границы массивов.

В принципе ничего страшного из-за его работы не случится, но будет сложнее ловить ошибки, так как программа не будет падать в условиях, когда должна бы, плюс могут быть проблемы с производительностью. Поэтому я на своих компах для разработки этот механизм отключаю, для этого надо немного поковыряться в реестре:

В ветках

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE и HKEY_CURRENT_USER`

`Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers\your_application.exe`

удаляем запись `Fault­Tolerant­Heap`, тем самым деактивируем FTH для вашей программы.

Но если программа продолжит падать, windows может снова включить для нее FTH. Чтобы этого избежать, можно выключить механизм FTH совсем, для этого параметр

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\FTH\Enabled` выставляем в 0